# Enumerate partitions of a set into subsets of equal size

Tags: r, algorithm, matlab

I have a set and I want to partition it into sub-set containing equal number of element.

I am looking for a fast algorithm and preferably not heuristic one.

**Hint:**

```
if  n= number of elements in the main set
    l= number of elements in each subset
```

**A brute force algorithm is:**

> 1-x <-All combinations of n things taken l  at a time without
>   repetition. |x|=nCl=n!/(l!*(n-l)!)
>   2-y <-All
>   combinations of x things taken n at a time without repetition. |y|=xCn
>
> 3-Select subsets in y such as there is no any overlap within their
>   elements.

The number of answers is:

```
n!/(l!^(n/l)*(n/l)!)
```

For instance if  `S={a,b,c,d}` and if subsets with 2 elements to partition set S is desired:

The set x is  :

```
   (a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d),(c,d)
```

The set y (potential answers)is  :

```
{(a,b),(a,c)}
{(a,b),(a,d)}
{(a,b),(b,c)}
{(a,b),(b,d)}
{(a,b),(c,d)}       
{(a,c),(a,d)}
{(a,c),(b,c)}
{(a,c),(b,d)}
{(a,c),(c,d)}
{(a,d),(b,c)}   
{(a,d),(b,d)} 
{(a,d),(c,d)}   
{(b,c),(d,d)}   
{(b,c),(c,d)}   
{(b,d),(c,d)}
```

and the correct answers are :

```
S1={(a,b),(c,d)}
S2={(a,c),(b,d)}
S3={(a,d),(b,c)}
```

The mentioned algorithm is useful only when n is small. 
For instance when:

```
 n=90, l=3 =>
|x|=117480 
|y|=1.28827732e+318
and the number of correct answers is `2.533601e+82`.
```

So the algorithm is not practical for the most case due to time performance and memory issues.

Even having and running an efficient algorithm would be time consuming as the number of results is a lot. For instance in the above problem the number of answers = `2.533601e+82`

I am not expertise in the set theory so maybe it is  a well known problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at solving the problem yourself?

Comment: You will have better luck including your attempts and asking about the code itself rather than asking for an abstract solution.

Comment: I have added a naive algorithm to the problem

Comment: I disagree with the prior comments, and don't think that a naive algorithm adds value to this question.  But you have it now and there's no reason to remove it.

Comment: I believe your algorithm description could stand a little cleaning up. For one, is `y = xCn` or `xCl`. Second, if `n >= (x / n) + 1`, no combination of `n` subsets of length `n` would work. Can you explain precisely what you need keeping in mind the edge cases? Thanks.

Comment: asb please see the definition of combination . I have added it  to the text.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be close...hope you're using java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c","d"})));

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
      String tokenA = tokens.get(i);
      for (int x = (i + 1); x < tokens.size(); x++) {
        String tokenB = tokens.get(x);
        //String tokenC = tokens.get(x + 1);

        System.out.println(tokenA + "-" + tokenB);
      }
    }
  }
```

my output is

```
run:
a-b
a-c
a-d
b-c
b-d
c-d
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it just provide all combinations with 2 element

Comment: In R, the above program may be written as `combn(letters[1:4], 2)`.  Still doesn't answer the question though.